# How do you assign li items different classes depending on what is selected on dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that allows the user to select a category from a dropdown menu, then type into an input box. When they hit enter on the input box, a list item is created.

My goal: Based on what category they chose from the dropdown, the list item is assigned a different class. In the CSS, the class would have specifications about positioning (right now, it only has specific background colors for each). Final result would be that each list item is grouped in a different position on the page based on which category the user chose. (For example, all list items of category 1 will be on the bottom-left of the page, and all list items of category 2 will be on the bottom-right of the page, etc, etc...)

In the JS file I have indicated the place where I think the relevant code should go, but as for what to put there I am rather lost.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mlynn/jyrbepyz/3/

HTML:

```
<section id="heady">
        <div style="text-align: left;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:left;"><b><a href="index.html">Site</b></a></p></div>

        <div style="text-align: right;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:right;">    
                <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
                <a href="index.html">Generic</a> |
                <a href="index.html">Elements</a> |
                <a href="index.html">Sign Up</a>
        </div>


    </section>

    <section id="wrapper">
        <br><br>
        <img src="images/blacksquare.png" width="525" height="197"></img>

        <br><br><br>


        <div>
            <div style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;float:left;">        
                <ul class="navbar cf">
                    <!-- <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li> -->
                    <li style="width:200px;">
                        <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">#</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>                                                               


            <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Enter a To-do and hit enter">
                </form>
                <br>

                <!-- <ul class="active">
                    <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                    <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                    <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
                </ul> -->

            </div>



            <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
                <ul class="active">
                    <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                    <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                    <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>     


        <div class="Category1">
            <!--list items that user assigned "1" from dropdown menu would be placed in this div-->
        </div>

        <div class="Category2">
        </div>

        <div class="Category3">
        </div>

        <div class="Category4">
        </div>                    

        <div class="Category5">
        </div>

        <div class="Category6">
        </div>

        <div class="Category7">
        </div>


    </section>



    <section id="feety">
    I believe I exist
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
/*adder*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);


 * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


html {
 background:teal;
}


body {
    /*background:url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/4657039731.jpg');*/
}


a {
    color: #D9D9D9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}



#heady {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#222;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:teal;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative; 
}


#feety {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:darkslateblue;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}





.Category1 {
    background:blue;
}


.Category2 {
    background:green;
}

.Category3 {
    background:yellow;
}

.Category4 {
    background:orange;
}

.Category5 {
    background:purple;
}

.Category6 {
    background:gold;
}

.Category7 {
    background:maroon;
}

/* clearfix */
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
   * zoom: 1;
}


ul.navbar {

  background:white; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:gray;
  border-width:1px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;

}


.ActiveListItem:after {
    content: "\25BC\00a0\00a0";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:right;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}




ul.navbar li a.ActiveListItem {
    background:white !important;
    color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:3px 5px !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    margin-left:14px;/* got the activeitem centered with the list text this way*/
    margin-right:0px;

}

ul.navbar li {
    position: relative;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;

}

ul.navbar li a:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > a {
    background:#a6d0e1; /*Leaving for now, but keep in mind things bold slowly when you change this to gradient*/
    color: #333;
    font-weight:900;

}

    ul.navbar li ul {
        margin-top: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: none;
        z-index: 99;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
        0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    }

ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }

.hidden { display: none; }







/*Lister*/



.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

form {  }

input,
ul {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
}

input {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.lister ul {
    list-style: square inside;
    padding: 10px;
}

.active { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.inactive { display: none; }

.lister li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #34495e;
}

.lister li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #dadfe1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.lister li > a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #22313f;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.lister li > a:hover {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #c0392b;
}


.lister li:before {
    content: "#";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:left;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}
```

JS:

```
// sub menus identification
$(function() {
  $('.navbar ul li a').click(function(){  
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > a').text($(this).text());
    $('.navbar > li > ul').addClass('hidden');
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(100);
  });
  $('.navbar > li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.ActiveListItem').click(function(){        
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
  });    
});









//newList

$(document).ready(function() {  

    var ul = $('.lister ul'),
        input = $('input');

    input.focus();  

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (input.val() !== '') {
            var inputVal = input.val(),
                activeNumber = $('.ActiveListItem').text();


            if (activeNumber == "1") {
                /*I guess the fantasy code goes here...?*/
            }

            ul.append('<li>' + activeNumber + ' ' +inputVal + '<a href="">X</a></li>');
            if (ul.hasClass('inactive')) {
                ul.removeClass('inactive')
                    .addClass('active');
            }
        };
        input.val('');
        return false;
    });

    ul.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();

        if (ul.children().length == 0) {
            ul.removeClass('active')
                .addClass('inactive');
            input.focus();  
        }
    });

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mlynn/jyrbepyz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a data attribute on the dropdown `li` element with the class name.

```
<li><a href="#" data-newclass="exampleClass">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-newclass="anotherClass">2</a></li>
...
```

Move data attrbute from li to .ActiveListItem:

```
$('.navbar ul li a').click(function() {  
    var newClass = $(this).attr('data-newclass');
    $('.ActiveListItem').attr('data-newclass', newClass);
    ...
});
```

On form submit you get the data attribute. Like this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var inputVal = input.val();
    var activeNumber = $('.ActiveListItem').text();
    var newClass = $('.ActiveListItem').attr('data-newclass');
    ...
});
```

Now you can set the class to any element you want by using `.addClass()`.

Comment: Where do you put the .addClass() code? I have something like:

if (activeNumber == "1") { ul.addClass('.exampleClass'); } and in my CSS I have .exampleClass { background:blue; } for testing purposes. But when I have "1" selected on dropdown, the resulting li item doesn't look any different than the other dropdown selections. I know I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you send me a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured out how to get the code situated. Thank you :>!